# snmp, how to retrieve ip connected to the router with MIB-II

Tags: snmp

I want to create a program that acts as manager and that queries the router (or sets a trap) to obtain the list of ip connected to it. My router has these functionalities: SNMP v1, v2c, built-in MIB-I, MIB-II agent.
Is it possible to retrieve these informations quering the MIB-II agent of the router in a standard way (not vendor dependent)?

Bye

Answer (score 0):

The Address Translation table (OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1) contains arp table of the device.
This will show you list of all devices from the network, which are (or have been recently) sending some traffic via router.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. 
This is interesting, anyway I think that this will be not sufficient for updated date, for example, noticing if a device isn't anymore in the network will be a problem.. right?

Comment: Yes, this alone will be not sufficient, but you can always combine it with ICMP ping to verify if each node is reachable.